# Async .sort() in dart

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart, async-await

I am working with dart/flutter, and i need to sort large values ​​(10,000, 20,000 90,000 100,000 items ) and the application crashes for a few seconds due to the volume of very large data being processed. my doubt is: Is there any way to use the sort() function as async, to show the loadingProgressIndicator() when the data is sorte?

like this:

```
listFilt.sort((a,b)=> a.compareTo(b))
```

And i want to tranform in something like:

```
 showCircularIndicator = true;
 await listFilt.sort((a,b)=> a.compareTo(b));
 showCircularIndicator = false;
```

I know that sort() is synchronous function but have any way to transorm in asynchronous function?

Comment: Look into Isolates. (It's a common misconception that Dart's async capabilities will somehow compensate for the single thread of execution being blocked in a compute-intensive task.)

Comment: Do you mean that your program *freezes* for a few seconds? "Crashes" means that it fails irrecoverably.

Comment: @jamesdlin only freezes for a few secondes (3, 4 or 5 secs) 
then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [compute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html), here is the example of sorting photos according to title.

```
List<Photo> sortPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {
  photos.sort((a,b) => a.title.compareTo(b.title));
  return photos;
}

...
final List<Photo> photos = await ...
final result = await compute(sortPhotos, photos);
```